# Positioning of iframe in blogger

Tags: iframe, blogger

I'm trying to embed someone's blog (with their permission) into my blog. I'm doing this with an iframe, and also only want to crop part of his blog. I've found some code that removes some of the elements (to make more room) on the static page where I want to embed his blog, and also how to move his blog within the iframe so that it is cropped to the bit I want.

My only problem now is that I want the bit I am cropping to appear in the main-wrapper of my blog so that it looks more integrated. If you look on the test page of my blog, you'll see what I mean....

damianp1.blogspot.co.uk

The main wrapper (if that's what it's called) is floating above the iframe.

Here is the html I used to do the above...

```
<style type="text/css">

.blog-pager, .footer, .comments, .post-footer, .main-background, .feed-links, .post-   title, .sidebar, #Attribution1, #footer-wrapper .sidewrapper { display:none !important;}
#main-wrapper {width: 95%; float:none; margin: 0 auto !important;}

</style>
</b:if>
<style>]


#outerdiv {width: 250px; overflow:hidden; position: relative;}
#innerdiv {position: absolute; left: -360px; top: -100px;clip:rect(250px 1700px 20000px 329px);}
</style>

<div id="outerdiv">
<div id="innerdiv">
<iframe width="1000" height="30000" src="http://birdingsthelens.blogspot.co.uk/"  id=’innerdiv’ scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

How can I get the cropped bit of blog into the main wrapper, or is there a better way of doing this?
As you can probably tell I know nothing of HTML, I'm just copying and pasting bits of code I've found from the web!

Cheers, Damian

Answer (score 0):

To get the iframe inside the blue area you will need to remove all styles relating to `innerdiv` (including the `div` tag itself) as they're not needed...

```
<style type="text/css">

.blog-pager, .footer, .comments, .post-footer, .main-background, .feed-links, .post-   title, .sidebar, #Attribution1, #footer-wrapper .sidewrapper { display:none !important;}
#main-wrapper {width: 95%; float:none; margin: 0 auto !important;}

</style>
</b:if>
<style>]


#outerdiv {width: 250px; overflow:hidden; position: relative;}
</style>
```

**Edited:**

```
<div id="outerdiv" style="width: 600px; overflow: hidden">

<iframe width="850" style="position: relative; left: -280px; top: -290px" height="30000" src="http://birdingsthelens.blogspot.co.uk/" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Using a relative position you can crop out any unwanted content.

*Note:* If you want the content to be the page width, rather than the standard size of the blue area, here are the dimensions:

```
<div class="post-outer" style="width:875px">
<div id="outerdiv" style="width: 900px; overflow: hidden">
<iframe width="1300" style="position: relative; left: -440px; top: -290px" height="30000" src="http://birdingsthelens.blogspot.co.uk/" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your help. I used your code above on the page test2 on my blog. The iframe is now within the blue area, but its showing the full page again, and not just the cropped area as is shown in page 'test'. Is it possible to crop the page and have it within the blue area? Thanks again, Damian.

Comment: Wow. That's amazing!! Thanks very much.
That looks exactly how I wanted it! I've spent hours trying to figure this out so am really grateful. I'll try and remove that bit of blue box that appears above the iframe now.

Thanks again, Damian.